# create sql server database with same attributes and size

Tags: sql-server

Hi All: I'm new to SQL DBA and I have to perform this task in production. Create a database ABC with same attribute and size as database XYZ. Is this the simple restore operation? Take a full backup of XYZ and restore the .bak file. Is that all?

Comment: yes just take backup of database XYZ and just restore and name it as ABC

Comment: welcome any further doubts we are here there for you @sri ram

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Restore the full backup of XYZ db under the name of ABC. That's all

Answer (score 0):

it can be achieved in other way also if u are using ms2012 .
go to ur database abc and right click ... then tasks and then generate script . script all and next step and in advance tab just select (schema and data) and save it where u want.
then in database xyz open this script file and erase till use database abc  and at last alter database abc and then execute .. 
done..